# I would like this table to be aligned and spaced correctly, I get unequal spacing and headers mot uniformed

Tags: vertical-alignment

```
    % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet2'
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{ABCD}
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4}
     & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{A}} & 0.6914*** & 0.3777*** &  
      0.3047*** & 0.3052*** & 0.3088*** & 0.2486*** \\
      \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{}} & (0.122) & (0.128) & (0.086) & (0.086)
     & (0.090) & (0.079) \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{B}} &       & 0.0027*** & 0.0014**
     & 0.0014** & 0.0013** & 0.008 \\
      \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{}} &       & (0.000) & (0.001) & (0.001) & 
   (0.001) & (0.001) \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{C}} &       &       & 0.0099*** & 
  0.0099*** & 0.0096*** & 0.0087*** \\
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{}} &       &       & (0.003) & (0.003) &  
 (0.003) & (0.003) \\
 \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{C}} &       &       & -0.0012*** & 
  -0.0012*** & -0.0011*** & -0.0011*** \\
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{}} &       &       & (0.000) & (0.000) & 
  (0.000) & (0.000) \\
   \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{D}} &       &       &       & -0.0001 & 
   -0.0001 & -0.0001 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{}} &       &       &       & (0.000) & (0.000) & 
  (0.000) \\
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{E}} &       &       &       &       & 
 0.0036 & 0.0033 \\
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{}} &       &       &       &       & (0.003) & 
  (0.003) \\
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{F}} &       &       &       &       &  
   & 0.0007** \\
   \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{}} &       &       &       &       &       &
   (0.000) \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Reg. Effects}} & yes   & yes   & yes   & yes   & 
 yes   & yes \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Obs}} & 100   & 100   & 100   & 100   & 100   & 
 100 \\
   \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Instruments}} & 8     & 9     & 10    & 11
    & 12    & 13 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Hansen P Value}} & 0.117 & 0.039 & 0.106 & 
    0.095 
    & 0.151 & 0.188 \\\hline\hline
   \multicolumn{7}{c}{Robust standard errors in parentheses.   *p $<$ 0.10,
  **p $<$ 0.05,     ***p $<$ 0.01} \\
    %\bottomrule
   \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
  \end{table}%
```

Comment: Once again a question  with just a fragment of code, a messed up title, no body. Do you expect us to read minds? Please post a compilable minimal working example.

Comment: Table conversioni tools generate a clutter of useless commands. If you would do your tables by hand, you would be faster. Right now, this is a *Do it for me* question without any sign that you tried to improve the code yourself.

Comment: Looking at the output of that code, I for one do not understand what you want to do differently. Can you try to explain in more detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: A phrase such as "aligned and spaced correctly" is rather vague. Please tell us what *you* understand to be "correct".

Comment: A sidenote: Please use the correct minus symbol for negative numbers, not hyphens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `S` column type of the `siunitx` package to align all numbers on their decimal markers. The `S` column type also performs rounding (if so instructed); this is useful here as some coefficients are reported with four digits after the decimal marker whereas their associated standard errors are reported with only three digits. I was taught that the point estimates and standard errors should always be shown with an equal number of digits.

Incidentally, since your posting didn't exactly over-specify what you want to achieve in terms of formatting, I had to make a lot of design choices. If some of these choices aren't to your liking, you need to speak up and state clearly and explicitly what it is you want to achieve. I'm simply terrible at mind-reading; my apologies.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\sisetup{table-format=-1.3,
         input-symbols={()},
         table-space-text-post={***},
         round-mode=places,
         round-precision=3
         }
\centering
\caption{ABCD} \label{tab:addlabel}
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\bfseries}l *{6}{S} @{}}
\toprule
 & {\textbf{1}} & {\textbf{2}} & {\textbf{3}} 
 & {\textbf{4}} & {\textbf{5}} & {\textbf{6}} \\
\midrule
A & 0.6914*** & 0.3777*** & 0.3047*** & 0.3052*** & 0.3088*** & 0.2486*** \\
  & (0.122) & (0.128) & (0.086) & (0.086) & (0.090) & (0.079) \\
B & & 0.0027*** & 0.0014** & 0.0014** & 0.0013** & 0.008 \\
  & & (0.000) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\
C & & & 0.0099*** & 0.0099*** & 0.0096*** & 0.0087*** \\
  & & & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.003) \\
C & & & -0.0012*** & -0.0012*** & -0.0011*** & -0.0011*** \\
  & & & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) \\
D & & & & -0.0001 & -0.0001 & -0.0001 \\
  & & & & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) \\
E & & & & & 0.0036  & 0.0033 \\
  & & & & & (0.003) & (0.003) \\
F & & & & & & 0.0007** \\
  & & & & & & (0.000) \\
\midrule
Reg.\ Effects & {yes}   & {yes}   & {yes}   & {yes}   & {yes}   & {yes} \\
Obs & {100} & {100} & {100} & {100} & {100} & {100} \\
Instruments & {8} & {9} & {10} & {11} & {12} & {13} \\
Hansen P Value & 0.117 & 0.039 & 0.106 & 0.095 & 0.151 & 0.188 \\
\bottomrule\addlinespace
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\small Robust standard errors in parentheses. * $p < 0.10$, ** $p < 0.05$, *** $p < 0.01$.} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but I prefer to use 4 decimal places for the coefficients, if I change the precision to 4 it overlaps with the asterisks that denotes significance

Comment: @James - If you don't want siunitx to perform rounding (to 3 digits in the answer I gave), do not change `round-precision=3` to `round-precision=4`. Instead, you should (a) omit the options `round-precision=3` and `round-mode=places` entirely and (b) change `table-format=-1.3` to `table-format=-1.4`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, Excel2LaTex is not the best way to make tables in Latex. I would suggest something like the tool that TexStudio has built in, or better, learn how to do it manually, (using an IDE of course).

In your case, your problem is that your tables are all **left-justified**, it is the `l` in your code in `\begin{tabular}{lllllll}` and `\multicolumn{1}{l}`. You can fix it by changing the `l` into an `r` for **right-justified**. Giving an output like the one below.

### Output

Here the first three rows are right justified (`\multicolumn{1}{r}`) and the rest are left. I am not sure that is what you are looking for. (Also you might have a typo in row 4 using again the letter **C** ).
[image: difference between left and right justified]

The best solution that I have to offer to you, is modify the Excel tables directly. Excel2LaTex copies your exact table configuration, cell size, font color, text alignment, etc. Therefore, I would suggest you modify your tables before you convert them to LaTex form.